# Why would my Dwarves decide that the Platonic solids are divine?

Tags: mathematics

**My Idea**

I’ve decided that my Dwarves are the foremost experts on matters mathematical and geometrical. Further, they believe that numbers are the key to unlocking the “secrets of the gods.” One idea I have is that they believe the [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) are divine, but I don’t know enough about geometry to figure out what might lead them to this conclusion.

**My Questions**

1. Are there aspects of the Platonic solids that are significant in other area of mathematics which could explain the Dwarves’ conclusion?
2. How could those aspects be applied to things like architecture? (I’m thinking the Dwarves don’t try to build their structures as Platonic solids but they do try to reflect them, if only in things like angles, the height of the walls being divisible by certain numbers, and so forth.)

Comment: *"Don’t try to build their structures as Platonic solids":* Tetrahedrons and cubes are quite reasonable as architectural shapes.

Comment: @AlexP that would make a valid frame challenge as an answer.

Comment: @AlexP True, but I was referring to the other Platonic solids in particular.

Comment: because the mighty god Gygax uses those solids to determine the fates of mortals.

Comment: *numbers are the key to unlocking the “secrets of the gods"* This is cryptology isn't it ? Or inaccessible cardinals, used for proving certain theorems (truth) ?

Comment: But the Platonic Solids _are_ divine! What do you mean??

Comment: Does your setting have magic?  Or can the setting have physics that behave differently with respect to Platonic solids?  Or does it have to be an explanation that'd potentially make sense in the real-world?

Comment: Historical note: I suspect that what some ancients may've found so fascinating about Platonic-solids wouldn't be _specifically_ the solids themselves so much as the notion of purely abstract objects.  Today, pure-abstraction isn't so novel, so modern-readers might have difficulty finding the same sense of wonder that the ancients may've had.

Comment: Since when has anyone ever needed a _reason_ to decide that something is divine?

Comment: Does your world support a (divine?) law preventing imagery/worship of *people* ?  [That seems to have nudged Islamic design down the geometric path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_geometric_patterns) ... Not that you have to carry it to *that* extreme to find [real-world examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_geometry) .

Comment: @AC It depends on the gods. The good gods hold that worship is inward & focuses on the connection one has with the god. Thus, while they don't oppose imagery of them, they do oppose directing worship at those images. The evil gods don't care either way but will use worship directed at images of them to their advantage in various ways. So it's less about the image & more about where the worship is being directed. If it's an idol, the good gods don't like it but the evil gods do. If it's just a work of art, the good gods don't mind but the evil gods feel cheated of a foothold to manipulate folks

Comment: I mean, *Plato himself* thought they were divine, so there's that.  His statement about the dodecahedron in particular: "*...the god used [it] for arranging the constellations on the whole heaven*" shows that.  The other 4 he associated with the elements of fire (tetrahedron), earth (cube), air (octahedron), and water (icosahedron).  Aristotle proposed a 5th element of ether to correspond to the dodecahedron.  Kepler tried to arrange the heavens onto inscribed spheres and platonic solids.  There's plenty of real-world history of assigning divinity to theses shapes.

Answer (score 50):

**Dwarves worship crystals.**

[image: icosahedron]

https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/icosahedron/

Of course they do.  Crystals are how the earth sings.  And crystals recapitulate the platonic solids, which are the [Platonic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms); the ultimate truths of Earth behind the crystals.

Comment: Cristals in general have a limited number of shapes too - but there are surprisingly many. You can even stack spheres in three different optimal ways.

Comment: There are lots of crystals and crystalline structures other than just the platonic solids.

Comment: Great answer.  Yes, dwarves are "close to" crystal matters, just as fish beings are intimate with water.  They are crystal-benders.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel: There are an unlimited number of optimal ways to pack spheres, but there are only two "simple" ones (fcc and hcp). If bcc is the third option you're thinking of, it's not optimal.

Comment: I can see my Dwarves being introduced to the Platonic solids through crystals & perhaps they saw them as a sign of the divine in nature as they came to understand why they are unique among polyhedrons. The more they analyzed these shapes (& they would analyze the heck out of 'em,) the more fascinating they would become. I've certainly gained a greater appreciation for the Platonics solids the more I learn about them.

Comment: Ideal crystal forms and Platonic solids are [two different categories, with partial overlap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid). "The tetrahedron, cube, and octahedron all occur naturally in crystal structures. These by no means exhaust the numbers of possible forms of crystals. However, neither the regular icosahedron nor the regular dodecahedron are amongst them." The image you include is a pseudoicosahedron, without the full symmetry that is the *definition* of Platonic solids. Granted, crystals may give some inspiration, but they do *not* correspond directly to Platonic solids.

Comment: @RBarryYoung clearly not all crystals are holy then

Comment: A fantasy world presumably has magic and materials we do not have. So perhaps there are crystals that form the other platonics in this setting.

Comment: @nanoman: seems slightly pedantic; a [pyritohedron is a (slightly) irregular dodecahedron composed of identical irregular pentagons](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pyritohedron.html); we could regard it as nature's approximation to the ideal thing. I couldn't find numbers quantifying how irregular. Diamonds are also somewhat irregular yet valued by some (due to 1920s marketing, but that's another story).

Answer (score 41):

I don't see why you need a specific reason behind why dwarves would view platonic solids as divine. Especially since there were very similar beliefs in our real world going back centuries. Kepler for instance believed that the orbits of the solar system followed the surfaces of the five platonic solids nested inside one another. In *Mysterium Cosmographicum* he explicitly laid out his belief that this reflected the universe's divine ordering by god. Plato thought the entire world was composed of his five platonic solids, again as part of a divine construction.

The platonic solids are highly symmetric/organized yet at the same time very simple and elegant (indeed, it could be said that almost by definition they are the most elegant solids possible). These are all qualities that humans (and so maybe also dwarves?) have always attributed mystical significance to. It's probably a big part of why equilateral triangles (see the Eye of Providence, Star of David) have also been widely associated with god/gods, as well as the circle (cross cultural use of the halo in religion).

Comment: That's a good point. And that combination of symmetrical order & simple elegance would certainly be something that would appeal to my Dwarves, based on what I've come up with for them so far. I've also learned that some molecules arrange themselves into Platonic solids, which has me thinking that certain magic barriers work at optimal efficiency when they are shaped like Platonic solids. This would certainly give the Dwarves further reason to see these shapes as being connected with the secrets of the gods.

Comment: +1 for Kepler's model as precedent.

Answer (score 15):

What you're describing sounds similar to [Pythagoreanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoreanism). The ancient Greek philospher Pythagoras founded a school of philosophy that studied, among other things, mathematics and geometry, intertwining their studies with religious practice. Numbers became symbolic of intangible concepts, and great emphasis was placed on using mathematics to describe natural harmony in all its forms, whether it be the motion of the planets or the sound of harp strings. The Platonic solids represent mathematic ideals which are in many ways unique, so it's not much of a leap at all to imagine a school of thought that views these special shapes as being directly related to the gods themselves. Pythagoreans viewed the known Platonic solids as representing particular qualities unrelated to mathematics, like the dodecahedron representing health, so imbuing these shapes with divine qualities seems very plausible.

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer.  Plato studied with the Pythagoreans and developed his own slightly less mystical philosophy and metaphysics ([Platonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonism)) from them.  Like them he considered the five platonic solids to be "divine", largely because of the principle of "necessity" from Platonism.  See the quote from Plato at the end of this article: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath096/kmath096.htm

Comment: Someone on another forum suggested that the Platonic solids could represent fairness & justice due to their properties. This lines up with your point nicely, so I think this is something I need to give further consideration. Rather than having the Platonic solids be associated with the classical elements (earth, water, air, fire, ether,) which wouldn't work in my setting as well, I think I might have the Dwarves take a more philosophical view of them. Fairness could be one attribute they associate with them, but there could be others (at least five, I should think, one for each solid.)

Comment: @Patrick-Leigh  “Fairness” of the Platonic solids actually relates back to the Gygax-god semi-joke.  The Platonic solids are “fair and just” in the sense that they treat all of their faces, sides, vertexes and angles equally, which is also why they were chosen by Gary Gygax as the dice for D&D.  There are other shapes that treat all of their faces equally (which is sufficient for dice), but are not equal in all of the other respects.

Answer (score 9):

The Platonic solids are almost three-dimensional extensions of the counting numbers. They have a conceptual primacy that flows pretty directly from the collision between timeless mathematical truths and the fundamental nature of flattish Euclidean space.

Thus, the Platonic solids are universal: any intelligence will eventually discover them from first principles and careful observation of the natural world. Their primacy means the Platonic solids are one of the first "conceptual landmarks" that any intelligence is likely to encounter when it starts trying to understand the world, kind of analogous to how the monoliths in Clarke's *Space Odyssey* series are placed so as to only be reachable once Earth life reaches specific levels of development.

Imagine that the whole enterprise of physical science is a giant theme park. The Platonic solids are probably the statues near the entrance that people use to locate the bathrooms.

Standard fantasy Dwarves are usually a race of master craftsmen, which seems to gel with the method and flavor of basic geometric construction. I'd imagine they love how rapidly trigonometry allows a clever person to know the world. Consider that Hipparchus figured out the distance to the Moon around 140 B.C.

If you proved to some ancient peasants that a high-school trig cheat sheet can unlock some of the secrets of existence that seem most impenetrable, I wouldn't be surprised if they began to worship it. During WWII, some tribes in the Pacific started "[cargo cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult#Pacific_cults_of_World_War_II)" that worshipped U.S. Army cargo planes filled with ton upon ton of SPAM -- a shelf-stable, high-calorie meat-solid that is actually quite delicious.

So, imagine a race that genuinely *worshipped* science and its careful, relentless, ever-more-sophisticated search for the truth. It's not hard to imagine what might be the fruits of that orientation, regardless of its level of technological development. Think about a society that pursued truth with the same zeal that we pursue wealth. It would form a virtuous circle (ironically, one that is diametrically opposed to the real world).

These Dwarves would notice that the yield varies with their investment: the more faithful they are to their idol, the more reliably it unlocks concrete benefits, like some new technology or the ability to anticipate and avoid catastrophes (such as plagues). I suspect it would rid them of very many of our worst ills: violence, hunger, disease, prejudice, poverty, crime, pollution, corruption (*our* present dragon), and whatever comes after. No matter how that timeline maps onto their level of technology, they will be happier and healthier for it -- and, because of their explicit orientation toward one of the foundations of science: math & geometry, they would be directing their plaudits, and additional investments, where they belong.

Comment: RE: "*The Platonic solids are almost three-dimensional extensions of the counting numbers*" this is arguably true for the regular 2D shapes, there is one for each of the infinite counting numbers (though you have to hack one and two) and even one for zero.  However, you cannot make this case for the platonic solids because a) there only five of them and b) they do not even correspond in any consistent way with any range of the counting numbers.

Comment: (.. to be clear by "range" I meant sequential or adjacent range)

Answer (score 8):

### Reality of ideas

A long time back when I was feeling sad, I worked out what the perfect shapes were in four dimensions.  (... even the [120-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:120-cell.gif) - It was a sad time...)  That was before the days of just looking things up on the internet, and I'd never heard of 4D regular solids before, and yet I came up with the same answers that others had before me, and which you can look up so easily today.

There are some who insist that ideas only exist as the product of a human mind, or a historical situation - for some reason those people seem most often associated with Marxism, though I don't understand the connection.  Suggesting that there are "things" in the universe that exist as *ideals*, independent of humanity, even things that none of us will ever be able to hold in our hand ... it seems to have a religious implication.  Maybe that's what they don't like about it.

Whatever the reason, to see something other than self or circumstance, wealth, politics or history, or even the laws of physics, that is the same on every planet, that neither man nor computer can ever change - that has a comforting aspect to it.  It is a small faith for small minds, but *tangible*, even provable one might argue.

P.S.  If you go this way, be sure to note the connections between the perfect shapes.  The cube can be found inside the dodecahedron, and the tetrahedron inside the cube.  Each shape has an inverse (same for the tetrahedron) etc.  Your architectural artwork will be much more satisfying if it can evidence those transitions.

Comment: I think a 4 dimensional solid would be extremely heavy. You have only a 3 D cross section, but it should have the mass of the whole object. And yes, the question whether mathematics  would exist without us in interesting. Does 1 exist in nature? Does Pi? Does multiplication? Does Integration? The tetrahedron?

Comment: AKA. maybe the dwarves feel the Platonic solids are just so beautiful that they "surely can't" be mere inventions of the human mind, but must have pre-existed in nature independently of minds, waiting to be "discovered" like a watch on the ground

Comment: @benxyzzy That's actually perfectly in line with my setting, as there are gods. (In fact, the gods are caught up in what is essentially a Cold War of sorts.) The Platonic solids are divine, in a sense, though it's more that they're a result of the various natural laws the gods established when they shaped reality... at least before some of them went bad & started messing with things. However, I'm thinking that some of the Dwarves are actually reading too much into the Platonic solids & putting a too much emphasis on them, like focusing on the proverbial watch instead of the watchmaker.

Answer (score 4):

**Because divine things are elegant.**

Real life humans spent thousands of years trying to model planets as following circular orbits because that seemed like the most perfect shape for the gods to have chosen. The elegance of a circle comes from the fact that all points on its edge are equidistant from the centre. I would argue that a solid composed of only congruent, regular polygons is just as elegant as a circle. I think that this historical precedent is enough to make your readers not question if the dwarves assume that the gods also have an appreciation for elegance.

I'm not 100% sure if by "things like architecture" you mean art and culture in general, but I'll assume you're open to it...

In terms of how you could work that into their culture that's more a matter of coming up with little ideas rather than a general underlying explanation (in my opinion). Some ideas I have are:

**Put it in their counting systems**

We count in base ten, but have a few remnants of dozenal systems (eleven and twelve as opposed to firsteen and secondteen). In French, base twenty counting is common (97 = four twenties, ten, and seven "quatre-vignt dix-sept"). And around the world, base-60, 'sexagesimal' counting is employed for angles and measures of time. Particularly the latter is odd because time is counted in base ten for <1 second (milli-, nano-, etc -seconds), base 60 for hours and minutes, and then goes to 24 hours to a day. I think that splitting up days into patterns based on the number of faces on platonic solids may be interesting, something like:

1 day has 20 'hours', which each have twelve 'minutes', each of eight 'long intervals', each of six 'short intervals', each of four 'seconds'. In that system, each 'second' would be 1.875 human seconds, and the other units would work out to useful durations.

Other systems with multiple non-logarithmic orders of magnitude could follow similar patterns: ie currency systems, etc. You could also make them prefer counts of 4, 6, 8, 12, and 20, ie make hexameter common in their poetry, etc.

**Put it in their mythology and culture**:

Around the world, cultures apply significance to various small numbers, mostly arbitrarily. See "Rule of three", "lucky seven", "unlucky thirteen", and so on. (Granted these are current, Western examples and I'm sure that every number between one and twenty has been assigned cultural significance by one group or another.) Perhaps your dwarven children learn in school that arguments are most convincing when delivered with four main points, and fairy tales always have four variations of the same event.

**Dice!**

RPG players are used to platonic dice (plus ten sided dice), but to most people they're something of a curiosity. If platonic solids are more culturally significant, make common games that use them for your world.

**Use the shapes in their art**

This one is kind of obvious but: when carving stone, make embossed doedecahedrons, cut fancy deserts into tetrahedrons and perfect cubes, make the pommels of their tools in the shape of isocahedrons, cut gems into the same shapes, and so on.

**Post script**

If your dwarves are interested in platonic solids, they may be interested in their two dimensional equivalents, regular polygons, or in their [4d equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/120-cell) (which someone else has already mentioned) or in [interesting plane tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Regular_tilings).

Comment: In keeping with some other feedback I've received (here & elsewhere,) I'm thinking that they use dice shaped like Platonic solids in deciding punishments for crimes since the Platonic solids are "fair." Your other suggestions also have lot of merit to them. I also think that there would be a lot of games built around the Platonic solids. Perhaps that's seen as letting the gods join in on the fun.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics are subjective ([cf. category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics))), it's a point of view on reality (reality of ideas too).

[Monocrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_crystal) are the manifestation of atoms stacking, which lies on a certain number of symmetries, which are also [well described by *group theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_point_group), one of the many [algebraic structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) (other structures are arithmetics, analysis, etc).

Hence the shapes one see can be interpreted as a hint on algebras, [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) and mathematical fundations, as well as a hint on atoms, matter properties, quantum physics and fundamental physics.

This is hence clearly a platonic solid.

Elements featuring a certain group of symmetries can be used in architecture indeed. But their combination involves also a certain impression, feeling, which is to date not described by any algebraic structure.

Aside of this, *numbers are the key to unlocking the “secrets of the gods"*. This is cryptology isn't it ? Or inaccessible cardinals, used for proving certain theorems (ie., extending the known truth) ?

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what I'm thinking. Since numbers are a huge part of science & science is viewed as a way to uncover how the gods shaped Reality, numbers are thus the keys to the locks of the proverbial doors of knowledge. My Dwarves are not opposed to magic, but magic in my setting (at least Arcane magic) is very "science based," allowing one to bend but not break the laws of physics, like converting kinetic energy into another type of energy. Thus, the more scientific knowledge you have, the more effectively you can use Arcane magic. Mages in my setting have to be scientists.

Comment: @Patrick-Leigh Numbers are inerts and don't bring much, no knowledge or anything, what is a lot more important is functions, ideas, axioms, algebras, but they may rely on numbers to express few ideas, but not all. One can see that like ink on one hand (numbers) and painter+brushes+ ideas on the other hand (functions).